# Find the leading coefficient of the polynomial $P(x)=(-x^2+3x-1)^{93}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the leading coefficient of the polynomial $$P(x)=(-x^2+3x-1)^{93}$$ The authors of the problem say that the leading coefficient is determined by the coefficient of the $x^{2.93}$ term. And it is equal to $(-1)^{93}=-1$. I don't see why $2.93=186$ is the greatest degree of $x$, how can we conclude that? Then why the leading coefficient is equal to $-1$?

Comment: Do you know about the multinomial theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The every term of the polynomial $(-x^2+3x-1)^{93}$ will be this form : $(-x^2)^a(3x)^b(-1)^c\:\:(a+b+c=93, a,b,c\ge0)$.

The largest order of the term is when a is 93, b and c is 0.

Then the leading coefficient will be $(-x^2)^{93}(3x)^0(-1)^0$'s coefficient, which is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $(-x^2+3x-1)^2=(-x^2+3x-1) \cdot (-x^2+3x-1)$ and expand the product.
Which is the highest term ? which is its coefficient ?
And then, what happens if you multiply again by $(-x^2+3x-1)$ ?

Answer (score -1):

$x^{186}$ and $x^{93}$ are two powers of $x$ in which former is greater and leading coefficient the coefficient of the degree of polynomial which is $x^{186}$ AND THAT MINUS SIGN IS WILL NOT BE SQUARED ITS POWER WILL BE $93$ ONLY.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).